# lookaround explanation needed when adding commas to a number

Tags: regex

I would gladly appreciate some help in understanding what's going on in the code below. It's just not clicking. So, the snippet (taken from this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124))

```
s/(?<=\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+$)/,/g
```

converts a number 123456789 to 123,456,789. (`g` is the global flag). Now, say we have the number 1234. From my understanding `(?<=\d)` will place us in front of 1 like so 1|234. Then,  `(?=(\d\d\d)+$)` picks up where the look behind left off and evaluate the remaining digits. Since 234 matches the pattern (3 digit and one end line), our substitution takes place (1,234). I hope I got this right.

Now, I'm confused when I make my numbers bigger say 1234567. When I put this into a regex tester I get 1|234|567 but in my mind I expected 1234|567. So...why ? Why does the look ahead for 234 evaluate to true when 4 is not terminated by an end line ? Does this have anything to do with the global flag? Thanks.

Comment: Think of it as matching is always done _inbetween_ characters. And matching always procedes from left to right. When you look at a regular expression, try to imagine yourself inbetween the characters in the expression and line that up with the inbetween postion in the source string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lookahead looks for *multiples* of three digits: `(\d\d\d)+` matches 3, 6, 9, ... digits, and therefore it matches before `234567`.

And yes, the global flag has to do with the regex matching twice (although without it, as you can easily test, the result would be `1|234567`).

Let's see what happens when we go through the string `"1234567"`:

```
1.  1234567
   ^ (?<=\d) doesn't match - regex fails.
2. 1 234567
    ^ (?<=\d) matches "1", (?=(\d\d\d)+$) matches "234567"! MATCH!
3. 12 34567
     ^ (?<=\d) matches "2", (?=(\d\d\d)+$) doesn't match.
4. 123 4567
      ^ (?<=\d) matches "3", (?=(\d\d\d)+$) doesn't match.
5. 1234 567
       ^ (?<=\d) matches "4", (?=(\d\d\d)+$) matches "567"! MATCH!
6. 12345 67
        ^ (?<=\d) matches "5", (?=(\d\d\d)+$) doesn't match.
7. 123456 7
         ^ (?<=\d) matches "6", (?=(\d\d\d)+$) doesn't match.
8. 1234567
          ^ (?<=\d) matches "7", (?=(\d\d\d)+$) doesn't match.
```

Comment: Been trying to accept for the last 3 minutes. Thank you!